# Sort a list of items in particular order kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can I order a list of ProductInCart by its status? I need the list to show the following order PENDING, UNTAKEN, REPLACED and TAKEN products to show them sorted in a recyclerview.

```
val itemsSorted: List<ProductInCart> = products.sortedBy { ... }
```

```
data class ProductInCart(
  val product: Product = Product(),
  @SerializedName("status") private val _status: ProductInCartStatus? = ProductInCartStatus.DEFAULT,
...
```

```
  enum class ProductInCartStatus(val value: String) {
    @SerializedName("pending")
    PENDING("pending"),

    @SerializedName("taken")
    TAKEN("taken"),

    @SerializedName("untaken")
    UNTAKEN("untaken"),

    @SerializedName("replaced")
    REPLACED("replaced");

    companion object {
      val DEFAULT: ProductInCartStatus = PENDING
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field to your enum class that represent the order you want to get

```
  enum class ProductInCartStatus(val value: String, val order: Int) {
    @SerializedName("pending")
    PENDING("pending", 1),

    @SerializedName("taken")
    TAKEN("taken", 4),

    @SerializedName("untaken")
    UNTAKEN("untaken", 2),

    @SerializedName("replaced")
    REPLACED("replaced", 3);

    companion object {
      val DEFAULT: ProductInCartStatus = PENDING
    }
  }
```

Then sort the items with

```
  val itemsSorted: List<ProductInCart> = products.sortedBy { it._status.order }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a priority to each:

```kotlin
enum class ProductInCartStatus(val value: String, val priority: Int) {
    @SerializedName("pending")
    PENDING("pending", 1),

    @SerializedName("taken")
    TAKEN("taken", 2),

    @SerializedName("untaken")
    UNTAKEN("untaken", 3),

    @SerializedName("replaced")
    REPLACED("replaced", 4);

    companion object {
      val DEFAULT: ProductInCartStatus = PENDING
    }
}
```

Then you can sort them with their priority:

```kotlin
val itemsSorted: List<ProductInCart> = products.sortedWith { it._status?.priority }
```

Answer (score 1):

The general way is to implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in your class (or create a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) if that suits you better. But since you're using an enum, if you're happy to rearrange the ordering (and nothing else is relying on the current ordinals) you can just do

```
products.sortedBy { it.ordinal }
```

(or `sortBy` if you want to modify the list in place)

if you can't modify the code, you could make your own ordered list as a lookup, something like

```
val productOrder = listOf(PENDING, UNTAKEN, REPLACED, TAKEN)
products.sortedBy { productOrder.indexOf(it) }
```

or `sortedBy(productOrder::indexOf)` if you're into that (I am)